# Exception class must extend another Exception class. Why?

Tags: exception

I got the following error when i try to create a test class which it seems to be legitimate. But it complains error. I do not know what is issue in this class.

> Save error: testCustomException: Exception class must extend another
>   Exception
>   class testCustomException.cls /DMSand_25Apr2014/src/classes   line
>   2 Force.com save problem

**Test class:**

```
    @isTest
private class testCustomException {

    static testMethod void myUnitTest() {
        try
        {
            throw new CustomException('this ','is my ','message');
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            system.assertEquals('Script-thrown exception', e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Custom Exception class:**

```
public with sharing class CustomException extends Exception {
    public String ErrorCode {get;set;}
    public String ErrorType {get;set;}
    public String ErrorDescription {get;set;}

    public CustomException(String ErrCode, String ErrType, String ErrDesc) {
        this.ErrorCode = ErrCode;
        this.ErrorType = ErrType;
        this.ErrorDescription = ErrDesc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ensure you do not have a local class that you have called `Exception`; to check that extend `System.Exception`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Keith. As per you advice on other day, i have been naming the classes and other components so that it will not collide with the standard one. Here, i do not have a class with name "Exception".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that your test class name ends with Exception. Salesforce does not allow classes with names that end with Exception unless they extend the `Exception` class.

I'd suggest renaming your test class to `CustomExceptionTest` to get around this.

Answer (score 2):

After saving a class that extends an Exception you will get an error in the developer console when the class name does not end with Exception.

Try creating the Exception extends class directly from setup>Develop>Apex classes.

Answer (score 0):

A custom exception must tie into the Exception plumbing and therefore must extend a standard exception. To do what you're trying to do, just declare your exception in your class:

```
public class CustomException extends Exception {}
```

Comment: Thanks greenstork. Actually, i created the custom exception by extending the Super class Exception class first and created this test class and it throws error on saving it in Eclipse.

Comment: Fun thing is right now, at least using the developer console, if you try and create a class "TestException" it tells you the class must extend exception (kind of hard to do when you can't yet edit the body), and of course, if you create the class first, extending exception generates an error stating class name must end in exception, wtf